# Local extension of a function on an immersed submanifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Consider the following passage in Spivak's Differential Geometry book:

[image]

I am having trouble understanding where he says $g = \tilde{g} \circ i$ on $V \cap M_1$. Since $V$ is (I think) supposed to be an $M$-neighborhood of $p$, this seems like exactly what we *can't* do in general. For instance, if $p$ is the point in the left picture where the graph almost self-intersects, then it seems we cannot define $g$ this way on some $M$ neighborhood of $p$, because there isn't even such a chart $y$ on such a neighborhood. Perhaps he means $V \cap U_1$, where $U_1$ is some $M_1$-neighborhood of $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric: You seem to be correct. We only have $g=\tilde g\circ i$ on $U_1\cap V$. Obviously, the extension $\tilde g$ to a tubular neighborhood of $U_1$ in $M$ has nothing to do with the values of the original $g$ on points of $V\cap M_1$ "far away" (in $M_1$) from $p$.